# Cannot assign to `self.x` because it is borrowed

Tags: rust, ownership, borrow-checker

I have 2 functions:

```
// A simple struct
struct S {
    w: u8,
    h: u8,
    x: Vec<u8>,
    y: Vec<u8>,
}

// Implementation of the struct S
impl S {
    // Seems to work
    fn new(_w: u8, _h: u8, _x: &Vec<u8>, _y: &Vec<u8>) -> S {
        S {
            w: _w,
            h: _h,
            x: _x.clone(),
            y: _y.clone(),
        }
    }

    fn calc(&mut self) {
        let mut min_x = self.x.iter().min().unwrap();
        let mut max_x = self.x.iter().max().unwrap();
        let mut min_y = self.y.iter().min().unwrap();
        let mut max_y = self.y.iter().max().unwrap();

        // Here's the line that gives the error
        self.x = self.x
            .iter()
            .map(|v| norm_value(*v, *min_x, *max_x, 0, self.w))
            .collect();
    }
}

fn norm_value<A, B, C, D, E>(_: A, _: B, _: C, _: D, _: E) -> ! { panic!() }
```

1. `new` makes a new `S` object. This seems to work, but correct me if I did something horribly wrong and just happens to work.
2. `calc` tries to modify the members `x` and `y`.

The compiler reports this error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `self.x` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:28:9
   |
22 |           let mut min_x = self.x.iter().min().unwrap();
   |                           ------ borrow of `self.x` occurs here
...
28 | /         self.x = self.x
29 | |             .iter()
30 | |             .map(|v| norm_value(*v, *min_x, *max_x, 0, self.w))
31 | |             .collect();
   | |______________________^ assignment to borrowed `self.x` occurs here
```

Where did I borrow `self.x`? I am new to Rust but things like this make no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the variable bindings at the beginning of `calc` return shared references (`&u8`) to `self.x` and `self.y`, which means you can no longer mutate them.

In order to not be bound by these borrows at the point of the last assignment you can `clone()` the references to obtain regular `u8`s:

```
let mut min_x = self.x.iter().min().unwrap().clone();
let mut max_x = self.x.iter().max().unwrap().clone();
let mut min_y = self.y.iter().min().unwrap().clone();
let mut max_y = self.y.iter().max().unwrap().clone();
```

I'm not sure if this solves all your issues, because you didn't provide the signature of `norm_value`.

As for the `new` method, you'll probably want to change the signature to obtain them by value instead of by reference:

```
fn new(w: u8, h: u8, x: Vec<u8>, y: Vec<u8>) -> S {
    S { w: w, h: h, x: x, y: y }
}

let s = S::new(10, 10, vec![1, 2, 3, 4], vec![52, 10, 23, 56]);
```

Note that I removed the underscores - you don't need to prepend the function arguments with them, if you remove them it will still be clear to the compiler. Prepending variable identifiers with underscores is usually used to silence the `#[warn(unused_variables)]` warnings.

Comment: Indeed, this works. So, if I get it right: `min().unwrap()` returns a reference to an element of `self.x` which means the entire `self.x` is borrowed (or just one individual element? (min)). Finally, `clone()` copies the referenced value and frees the reference?

Comment: @DimChtz `iter()` returns an iterator over immutable references and it borrows the whole `self.x` or `self.y` (but not whole `self`).`min().unwrap()` returns the reference to the smallest element; it consumes the iterator, but keeps the borrow in force. `clone()` obtains the referenced value and frees the borrow, yes.

Comment: Things like these make me feel like rust is messed up, but I still like rust :P Anyways, thank you.

Comment: One last question: considering `new` signature, would this: `let mut s = S::new(10, 10, &vec![1,2,3,4], &vec![52, 10, 23, 56]);` be a correct way to call `new` or could it cause any memory issues?

Comment: @DimChtz no, this won't cause issues, but it would make more sense to get the `_x` and `_y` vectors by value instead of by reference - that way you won't need to allocate their memory twice, like in this call. One of the best features of Rust is that if the compiler allows something then it should be perfectly safe (unless you use `unsafe`, of course).